# Can we pass setState directly to the button element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Generally, i would pass setVisFalse as a prop to Modal and then define a button inside Modal component that calls it, but i want to make Modal dynamic such that, instead of a button it could be anything (another component) defining the onClick event listener.

The following code works fine, but i want to know is it correct approach?

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [vis, setVis] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      {vis && (
        <Modal>            // generally, i pass here a setVisFalse as a prop.
          <h1>Hello Modal</h1>
          <button onCLick={setVisFalse}>Close Modal</button> // directly defining onCLick here only.
        </Modal>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default class Modal extends React.Component {
  render() {                                                    // instead of definig a button here,
    return <div className="modal">{this.props.children}</div>      it should be already inside children
                                                                 
  }
}
```

Comment: you need ```vis``` value to become ```false``` when you press the button ?

Comment: Yes, this is fine. Your `Modal` component is just a UI abstraction that has no business rules. Its `children` handle their own affairs. This type of component design is done all the time.

Comment: @MarcCharpentier Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously want to pass the boolean to the the `vis` state so the way you are doing it won't achieve that
You need to do this instead

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [vis, setVis] = useState(false);
  const setVisState = () => {
        setVis(value => !value);
}
  return (
    <>
      {vis && (
        <Modal>            // generally, i pass here a setVisFalse as a prop.
          <h1>Hello Modal</h1>
          <button onCLick={setVisState }>Close Modal</button> // directly defining onCLick here only.
        </Modal>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: setVisState is a funcion i.e similar to toggleModal in your code, i just not mentioned in my code.

Answer (score -1):

use `useContext` API .

pros - can be used in any nested level of children.